# Function calls after the imported URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, local-storage

I have wrote a code to save some value in local storage during my startup. I have that function in `index.ts`  and a imported url of a another page called `abc.ts`. In that page I have used the value which I saved in Local storage during startup. My issue is my function calls before the URL and the value in `abc.ts` is showing `undefined`.

**index.ts**

```
var cache = require('store')
getEnvironmentVariables();
require('./abc.ts');
function getEnvironmentVariables() {
 cache.set('ENV', 'XXXXXXXXXXX');
}
```

**abc.ts**

```
var cache = require('store')
console.log(cache.get('ENV'));
```

> I have other files which runs after startup. I can use
>   `cache.get('ENV')` there perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Node.js is executing your code asynchronously, in order for your use case to work, you can try something like this:

**abc.ts**

```
var cache = require('store')
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(cache.get('ENV'));
}, 1000);
```